# "I want to look better in the eyes of my classmates." Is this good English?

Tags: idioms

The goal is to express my wish to be more acceptable and/or respected by my classmates.

Is

> I want to look better in the eyes of my classmates

the right way to put it?

Comment: According to [TheFreeDictionary](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+the+eyes+of+(someone)), it seems to be correct, if a bit awkward.

Comment: It's grammatically correct, idiomatic, and not at all awkward. It's essentially metaphorical, but that is not a crime in English. Just ask Shakespeare.

Comment: This is not at all awkward. Except for the missing period at the end it is a perfect English expression that means exactly what you intend according to your description.